# C program which accepts only integers 1-42 into array and they cannot repeat in function

Tags: c, arrays, function, range, scanf

Develop a program that will play the Lotto game. The program should allow a user to 
enter their 6 selected numbers and give them a set of options, each performing a 
specific requirement. You must store the 6 numbers in a 1-Dimensional array.

There are a number of requirements that your program must meet. Your program 
must be modularised (i.e. use functions) and each task should be dealt in a separate 
function. The program should display a simple menu to the user and each option in 
the menu will be implemented by calling a separate function. You must use pointer 
notation to access array elements - NOT subscripts

The requirements are as follows (each implemented in a separate function):

1. Read the 6 selected numbers from the keyboard. Perform any necessary 
   validation (error-checking) required (e.g. all numbers must be different, range 
   1-42, etc.). ***THIS IS THE PART WHICH I CANNOT DO***
2. Display the contents of the 1-D array containing your lotto numbers that you 
   entered.
3. Sort the contents of the array in increasing order (i.e. 1st element = smallest 
   number, 2nd element = 2nd smallest number, etc.). You may use any sorting 
   algorithm of your choice.
4. Compare your chosen lotto numbers in the 1-D array with the following 
   winning numbers:

1,3,5,7,9,11 - 42 (Bonus number)

5 Display the frequency of the numbers entered each time the user enters a new ***AND I HAVE NO CLUE HOW TO EVEN START THIS***
set of numbers (without exiting the program) on the screen. For example, it 
might display:

number 1 has been selected x times 
number 7 has been selected x times 
number 28 has been selected x times
etc.,

6 Exit program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define NUMBERS 6

 // Declare Prototype
 void getnumbers(int*);
 void displaynumbers(int*);
 void sortnumbers(int*);
 void comparenumbers(int*,int*);
 void frequencynumbers(int*);
 void exit();
 main()
 {


     int choice=0;
     int lotto_no[NUMBERS];
     int winning_no[NUMBERS]={1,3,5,7,9,11};

    do
    {   
        system("cls");
         printf("\n======================MAGIC Lotto======================");
         printf("\n\n\n--------------Use 1-6 to navigate the menu-------------");
         printf("\n\n\n1.Pick your 6 lucky numbers");
         printf("\n\n2.Disply your numbers");
         printf("\n\n3.Display your lucky numbers in increasing order");
         printf("\n\n4.Compare your numbers to see your prize!");
         printf("\n\n5.Frequency of the numbers entered each time");
         printf("\n\n6.Exit");
         printf("\n\n\n========================================================");
         printf("\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
         system("cls");//Clears the menu from the screen while we selesc an option from the Menu 

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            getnumbers(lotto_no);
        }
        if (choice == 2)
        {
            displaynumbers(lotto_no);
        }
        if(choice == 3)
        {
            sortnumbers(lotto_no);
        }
        if(choice == 4)
        {
            comparenumbers(lotto_no,winning_no);
        }
        if(choice == 5)
        {
            frequencynumbers(lotto_no);
        }
        if(choice == 6)
        {
            exit();
        }


        flushall();
        getchar();

    }



    while(choice>1 || choice<7);
} 
void getnumbers(int *lotto_no)
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter your numbers\n");
        for(i=0;i<NUMBERS;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &*(lotto_no+i) );

            if ( *(lotto_no+i) >0 || *(lotto_no + i ) <= 43 )
            { 
                continue;
            }

            else
            {
                printf(" Please enter a value in between 1 and 42");
                scanf("%d", &(*(lotto_no+i)));
            }
        }

}

void displaynumbers(int *lotto_num)
{
    int i;
    printf("Your lucky numbers are as follow:\n");
    for(i=0;i<NUMBERS;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(lotto_num+i));
    }
}

void sortnumbers(int *lotto_num)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int temp;

    for(i=0;i<NUMBERS;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<NUMBERS;j++)
        {
            if(*(lotto_num+i) > *(lotto_num+j))
            {
                temp=*(lotto_num+i);
                *(lotto_num+i)=*(lotto_num+j);
                *(lotto_num+j)=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Your lucky numbers are as follow:\n");
    for(i=0;i<NUMBERS;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",lotto_num[i]);
    }
}
void comparenumbers(int *lotto_num,int *winning_num)
{

    int i;
    int j;
    int c;
    int b;
    int g;
    c=0;
    b=42;
    g=0;

    for(i=0;i<NUMBERS;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<NUMBERS;j++)
        {
            if(*(lotto_num+i) == *(winning_num+j))
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<NUMBERS;i++)
    {
        if(*(lotto_num)==b)
        {
            g++;
        }
    }

    if(c==6)
    {
        printf("JACKPOT!!!");
    }
    if(c==5)
    {
        printf("HOLIDAY!!!");
    }
    if(c==4)
    {
        printf("NIGHT OUT!!!");
    }
    if(c==3&&g==1)
    {
        printf("CINEMA TICKET!!!");
    }
    if(c==4&&g==1)
    {
        printf("WEEKEND AWAY!!!");
    }
    if(c==5&&g==1)
    {
        printf("NEW CAR!!!");
    }
    if(c<3)
    {
        printf("MAYBE NEXT TIME QQ :(");
    }

}
void frequencynumbers(int *lotto_num)
{

}

void exit()
{
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a starting point, for example your code to read in the file and an attempt to validate the input?

Comment: What problems are you having with your `getnumbers` function?

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Sidenote: There is no reason to use overly complex address arithmetric with derefenrecing `*(lotto_no+i)`. Simply use array index operator `lotto_no[i]`.

Comment: ive tried the if statment but still doesnt have any affect on the numbers and lets number grater than 42 to be inputed. Yes it is

Comment: @user694733 i have to use pointer notations to acces arrays

Comment: Have a close look at the `(choice > 1 || choice < 7)` condition. Then think. Same thing for the `*(lotto_no+i) >0 || *(lotto_no + i ) <= 43 ` condition.

Comment: @TomFenech ive tried the if statment but still doesnt have any affect on the numbers and lets number grater than 42 to be inputed. Yes it is

Comment: @MichaelWalz There is nothing wrong with the menu as it works. I need this program to accept only inteegers between 1-42 in function getnumbers. Its still reads the numbers and whole program works but it still allows user to input values bigger than 42

Comment: @user3463615: still the condition `choice>1 || choice<7` is **always** true. The same applies for condition  `*(lotto_no+i) >0 || *(lotto_no + i ) <= 43`. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying task Number 1 & 5 here.

Lets see the first task

```
void getnumbers(int *lotto_no)
{
int i,j,temp;
printf("Enter 6 different numbers in the range 1-42\n");
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
     printf("Enter number %d ",i+1);
     scanf("%d",&temp);
     for(j=0;j<i;j++)
     {
          while( (temp == *(lotto_no+j)) || (temp<1 || temp>42)) //Error checking
          {
               printf("Wrong input. Please enter a unique number in the range 1-42");
               scanf("%d",&temp);
               j=0;
          }
     }
     *(lotto_no+i)=temp;
}
return
}
```

Now lets go for Task no 5. I'm taking another array `int frequency[43]={0}`. I'm creating another function `void UpdateFrequency(int *, int *)`. In this frequnency will be updated and this will be called each time user enters a correct input combination i,e we should call this function in task 1.

```
void UpdateFrequency(int *lotto_no, int *frequency)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<6;i++)
   {
       (*(frequency+(*(lotto_no+i))))+=1; //frequency[lotto_no[i]]+=1;
   }
return;
}

void frequencynumbers(int *lotto_no, int *frequency)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<6;i++)
   {
       printf("The frequency of number %d is %d\n",*(lotto_no+i),*(frequency+(*(lotto_no+i))));
   }
return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) there is one more thing. when i input numbers and for eg.i press letter my program just get crazy :/

Comment: @user3463615: What is happening when you enter input?

Comment: program crashes by infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is invalid:

```
if ( *(lotto_no+i) >0 || *(lotto_no + i ) <= 43 )
```

It means "if number is greater than 0 **OR** number is less **or equal** to 43.

Also you move on to the next number even if you enter incorrect number.

```
    for(i=0;i<NUMBERS;)
    {
        int number = 0;
        scanf("%d", &number);
        // Replace OR with AND, and fix the upper comparison operator
        if(number > 0 && number < 43 )
        { 
            lotto_no[i] = number;
            i++; // Only increase when number was correct
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" Please enter a value in between 1 and 42");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could go about answering your first question:

```
void getnumbers(int *lotto_no)
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter your numbers\n");
    for(i=0;i<NUMBERS;i++)
    {
        do 
        {
            printf("Please enter number %d, between 1 and 42\n", i+1);
            scanf("%d", lotto_no+i); // or &lotto_no[i] if you prefer
        } 
        while ( *(lotto_no + i) < 1 || *(lotto_no + i ) > 42 ); // or lotto_no[i]
        printf("Number %d accepted\n", i+1);
    }
}
```

I have removed the unnecessary `&` and `*` from your `scanf` as they are redundant. I reversed the inequalities so that the inner `do while` loop will continue for each number until a valid input is given.

An easy way to count the number of times a given number is entered would be to have an array of `bins`, one for each number. Then you could `scanf` into a temporary number and increment the corresponding element of `bins`:

```
void getnumbers(int *lotto_no)
{
    int i, n, bins[42] = {}; // initialise zeroed array
    printf("Enter your numbers\n");
    for(i=0;i<NUMBERS;i++)
    {
        do {
            printf("Please enter number %d, between 1 and 42\n", i+1);
            scanf("%d", &n); // read into temporary variable
        } 
        while ( n < 1 || n > 42 );
        lotto_no[i] = n; // assign to lotto_no
        ++bins[n-1];     // increment corresponding counter
        printf("Number %d accepted\n", i+1);     
    }
    for(i=0; i<42; ++i)
    {
        if (bins[i] > 0) printf("number %d entered %d times\n", i+1, bins[i]);
    } 
}
```